# Multiple instances of App are shown in recent app list

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-applicationinfo

I am facing an issue in android application that Multiple instances of App are seeing in recent list.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.CEC"
    tools:replace="android:theme,android:allowBackup,android:usesCleartextTraffic"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="false"
    android:taskAffinity=""
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:taskAffinity="${applicationId}.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.splash.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"
        tools:replace="android:exported">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I am calling my method for recreating current activity for apply locale changes.

```
fun recreateActivity() {
    val intent = getIntent()
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
    intent.putExtra("activity_locale_changed",true)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)
    finish()
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

After implementing this code sometimes App is working fine or sometime app is creating multiple instances inside recent app list.

I have checked [Multiple instances of app in recent app list of tablet(android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41358524/multiple-instances-of-app-in-recent-app-list-of-tabletandroid),
[Multiple Instances of the same app are generated in stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53552228/multiple-instances-of-the-same-app-are-generated-in-stack),
[multiple instance of same app in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506704/multiple-instance-of-same-app-in-android)

Comment: It's making android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:taskAffinity="${applicationId}.MainActivity.    Why you added these lines

Comment: My Android application is vulnerable to a recently discovered android vulnerability called strandhogg (task hijacking). This allows a malicious app to Hijack target application UI leading to showing false information to the victim such as a fake login page to steal user credentials.

I want to prevent this vulnerability from the app. So I took a step for remove this issue I used android:taskAffinity="${applicationId}.MainActivity".

Please let me know what can I do for resolving this issue??

Comment: I hope this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872989/android-task-affinity-explanation

Comment: Why are you setting the taskAffinity to an empty string in the `<application>` declaration?

Comment: @DavidWasser What should I be use??

Comment: The default taskAffinity is the package name. You should remove that and use the default.

Comment: I don't understand how setting taskAffinity to "{applicationId}.MainActivity" will help solve the strandhogg issue. If the attacker knows this he can use this instead of your package name to hijack the task.  Also, please explain how `MainActivity` is launched from `SplashActivity`. Also, if you can provoke the "multiple tasks in recents" issue, please use `adb shell dumpsys activity activities` to dump the task list and post the relevant parts of that (all the tasks that contain your app's activities) in your question.

Comment: @DavidWasser Firstly I did not use taskAffinity for the MainActivity. When the issue arise then I used android:taskAffinity="${applicationId}.MainActivity". In both cases application is creating double instances in the recent app list.

Comment: Please use the `adb shell dumpsys` command to get more info and edit your question and add that info there. Otherwise we can't help you.